# Creating trade engine steps

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, currencies, buy-bitcoins, trade

How cryptocoin trade engine works?  I want to build a simple trade engine(trading bot) in ruby on rails for cryptocoins. Can anybody lead me through proper steps. I am a newbie to cryptocoins.

Comment: @GregHewgill - It is easy to add a comment like this but couldn't get any answer from that

Comment: Please do not ask the same questions again, rather improve the first question and vote to reopen it. Your first question was closed as it is unreasonably scoped, so is this one. Perhaps you should try to do some research first in order to be able to ask more targeted questions.